# Designing Tables: One to many and one to one at same time?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm not sure if I'm modeling this type of relationship correctly, perhaps someone could provide some insight into whether or not this is sound:

Say we have a typical parent-children type relationship where each one parent could have many children, but we need to keep track of the parent's single (gasp) favorite child...

---

Table Parent

### - FavoriteChildID

and

---

Table Child

### - ParentID

so the links criss-cross, where one is a many to one, and the other is one to one. is this considered good design?  Would it be better to have a column in the child table where only one row could be flagged a favorite at any time? Something else?

Thanks.

Comment: i dont see any problem with this approach given a few conditions.  Are parents and children entirely distinct groups?  No grand-childre, grand-parents, etc? There is just one set of parents who are never children, and one set of children who are never parents?  children always have exactly one parent?

Comment: just add a colum to child parent table where your can save his favorite child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an additional table?

```
table favourite(
  ,parent_id
  ,child_id
  ,primary key(parent_id)
);
```

It would help if for all favourite-oriented queries.

Answer (score 1):

The best design in my opinion is the one that will prevent data inconsistencies and prevent people from having enough rope to hang themselves.

If you only want one favorite for a parent, then perhaps the parent should have a favoriteChildId column.

If you put a column for a favorite flag in the child, you'll have to do more work to ensure that two child records of the same parent can't both be marked as favorites.

If you suspect that in the future you may have more than one favorite, then the extra work may of course be worth it.

The design really depends on the relationships and whether or not there could be changes in the future to the possibility of different "favorite" relationships.

Comment: am I breaking any cardinal rules by keeping the favorite child link in the table? something just doesn't 'feel' right about it to me.

Comment: @user568377 - If you were linking parent to child as in a parent has N children, then you'd probably want either a 3rd table as Ronnis suggested, or you'd want to put a link back to the parent in the child tables.  But if there is only one favorite, then you should be fine either way.  If you don't **ever** want more than one favorite, then give the parent a favoriteChildId.  It's really up to you and the decision should be based the requirements of your application.